# Quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a field with $\operatorname{char}k\neq 2$. The quadratic extensions of $k$ are in bijection with the non-trivial classes of $k^\times/k^{\times 2}$. As it is well-documented here in MSE, in the case of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, we can use Hensel's lemma to calculate these classes fairly explicitly. I wonder if we could use a different approach. I already know that
$$\mathbb{Q}_p^\times\cong\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$$
if $p\neq 2$. Is it possible to use this isomorphism to determine $\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times 2}$ and the quotient?

Moreover, is it possible to determine the extensions of higher degree in a similar fashion?

Comment: Absolutely! Even better, write the isomorphism more canonically as $\mathbb Q_p^\times \cong \mathbb Z_p\times \mathbb F_p^\times \times \langle\pi\rangle$ and you see that the square (or even $n$-power for $p\nmid n$) classes come exactly from even ($n$-th) powers of the uniformiser as well as square ($n$-power) classes in $\mathbb F_p^\times$. This argument is completely general and also tells you why considering $n$-power classes with $p\mid n$ is so whacky: it is only in that case that the  $\mathbb Z_p$ term has a contribution.

Comment: Dear @Mathmo123 thanks a lot for your enthusiastic comment! Perhaps this is obvious but why the square classes in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ play no role? Moreover, is it simple to find the square classes in $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$? (I guess in simple cases we can write it by calculating all the squares but it would be nice to know a general result.)

Comment: Because if $p\ne 2$, then $2$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z_p$, so $2\mathbb Z_p = \mathbb Z_p$. As for the square classes in $\mathbb F_p^\times$, I'm not sure what the most efficient method is. You do have quadratic reciprocity at your disposal though.

Comment: Thats cool! Do you know if it is possible to determine the extensions of higher degree in a similar way?

Comment: Yes. Exactly the same idea works. You have $K^\times = \mathcal O_K^\times \times \langle\pi\rangle$. And $\mathcal O_K^\times = \mathbb F_K^\times \times (1+\pi\mathcal O_K)$. When $|\mathbb F_K|$ is large enough, the logarithm map gives $1+\pi\mathcal O_K\cong \mathcal O_K$.

Comment: I don't think I understand your answer. What you say is how we calculate $K^\times$, which I indeed know. What I ask is how can we determine the higher degree extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. For example, I don't think that the cubic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are in bijection with the non-trivial classes of $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times/\mathbb{Q}_p^{\times 3}$. What does this group classify?

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your question. This type of idea works, but you have to be more careful. For cube classes: if $\zeta_3\in\mathbb Q_p$, i.e. if $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$, then the exact same idea works: by Kummer theory, every cubic extension is obtained by adjoining a cube root. If $p\not\equiv1\pmod 3$ and $p\ne 3$, then every unit is a cube (by Hensel's lemma, using the fact that every element of $\mathbb F_p^\times$ is a cube). There's always the unique unramified extension....

Comment: .... Any other extension is totally tamely ramified, so equal to $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt[3]\pi)$ for some uniformiser... and because every unit is a cube, there is only one such extension.

Comment: That is incredible. If you would like, write what you just said in an answer and I'll gladly accept it! Have a great day, @mathmo123